# how to add % symbol at the end textField in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I want to make a custom text field which will display the amount and (%) symbol
can anyone please tell me how can i acheive this.
if i enter 12 it should auto insert 12%

in UIKit it will be like textField.text = "(text) %"

[image]

```
struct UiTextFieldRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.placeholder = "Enter your text"
        textField.text = "\(text) %"
        return textField
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

issue with this code is it is showing % sign before i start writing.
all i want want is when i start writing in the field it should postfix the % sign

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for this i made a function and on right side put a image as percentage that fixed my issue

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.rightView = makeImageForTextField()
        textField.rightViewMode = .always
        textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
                let toolBar = UIToolbar(
                    frame: CGRect(
                        x: 0, y: 0,
                        width: textField.frame.size.width,
                        height: 44
                    )
                )
                let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(
                    title: "Done",
                    style: .done,
                    target: self,
                    action: #selector(textField.doneButtonTapped(button:))
                )
        
                toolBar.items = [doneButton]
                toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
                textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        return textField
    }
    
    private func makeImageForTextField() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "percent"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .black
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return button
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TextField("", value: $input, format: .percent )
```

Answer (score -2):

For the cases like this, **please show your code**. Because I'm not sure this is an actual question, maybe you haven't even started coding before asking it.

What exactly are you doing? To display the `%` symbol, just put in in the text (there're no formatting issues, it's not a special symbol etc):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int = 12
    var body: some View {
        Text("$ \(number) %")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

And you'll get your view rendered:

[image]

Comment: I think OP is asking for TextField i.e. showing % during text input.

Comment: yes this is my question @ChrisR do you have any answer for this